# MS-Access leaves big gap/margin on the right and bottom of a chart

Tags: ms-access, charts

MS-Access leaves big gap/margin on the right and bottom sides of a any type of charts except modern charts. Is this problem known and how could it be resolved?

And here is a screenshot of a chart with too big margins.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help

**Edit:**

I've tested it with the following environments:

- Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit + Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2303 Build 16.0.16227.20202) 64 Bit
- Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit + Office 2013 32 Bit (VirtualBox)
- Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit + Office 2007 32 Bit (VirtualBox)

The result is as follows:
If the scale under Windows display settings is set to 100% the margins behave properly and there is no problem with excessive gaps on the right and bottom sides. However, the more you increase the scale the bigger get the margins.

Important:
If there are multiple monitors connected to the PC, you must set the scale for all of them to 100% to get rid of the margin’s misbehavior. In my first tests I didn't realize that they all had to be set to 100%, so it didn't work at first.

**Remaining question:**
Changing the scale to 100% is IMHO not really a solution - at least not for me. Because I can't ask the users to change the scale before they can use the application. And changing the settings automatically via PowerShell or so, if it is possible at all, brings more complexity in to the application which is not desired.

I've also tried the three options for the chart-property zoom, clip and stretch with no success.

Modern charts do not have this problem but unfortunately, they do not provide most of the chart-types like scatter plot. So modern charts are not an alternative in this case.

Apparently, other people have similar problems with Access classic charts like this post shows:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65945791-f8e0-471d-8e15-ef8f66153cac/access-2013-how-do-i-get-my-charts-to-display-correctly?forum=officesetupdeploy

So, is there a solid solution or at least a better workaround?

Comment: Could try resizing chart area by grab and drag bottom right anchor. Otherwise, I would have to examine your chart design. Could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Unfortunately resizing does not work. When I resize the chart the ratio of filled and blank area remains the same.

I tried it on a blank new db. I created a table with data and then inserted a new chart in a form and in a report. In both cases the result is the same.

In another forum I've read that the screen resolution may cause this problem. So I changed the resolution from 125% to 100% in Windows 10. It doese not help.

Comment: You resized the chart area, not the outer chart object frame? Put chart in edit mode (double click or right click menu). Click on the chart area to make it active. Resize.

Comment: Actually, inner chart area should already be active when enter Edit mode.

Comment: I tried both - the chart area and the chart object itself. None of them work.
In the edit mode the right and bottom margins are 0 and can be resized. However when I go back to the design or form view it shows those margins. The chart functionality in Access seems to me to be buggy. I made a video of it and uploaded on YouTube. I hope it makes the issue clear.
https://youtu.be/gqf8LGypByc

Comment: Yes, odd. I have not encountered this. Could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. Does this happen with other charts and other data? Happen on another computer?

Comment: Thanks for the hint about testing it on other computers. After some testing I've noticed that the problem is related to the display-scale settings. I've edited my post and added my observations. Please have a look.

Comment: Interesting. I am using Windows 10 on laptop and my setting is already 100%. Changing it is not a pleasant result. The discussion you found seems to cover this topic. There is no 'solid solution'.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it seems hopeless :(